Why are sequential reads faster than sequential writes?
I have a matrix transposing code like this:
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii+=TILE_SIZE) {
    for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj+=TILE_SIZE) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < TILE_SIZE; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < TILE_SIZE; j++) {
                out[(jj + j)* n + ii + i] = in[(ii + i) * n + jj + j];
            }
        }
    }
}

This is a tiled version, where the pointer in reads sequentially from memory and pointer out writes strided to memory.
A second version of the same algorithms works in the opposite way: out writes sequential to memory and in reads strided. It looks like this:
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii+=TILE_SIZE) {
    for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj+=TILE_SIZE) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < TILE_SIZE; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < TILE_SIZE; j++) {
                out[(ii + i)* n + jj + j] = in[(jj + j) * n + ii + i];
            }
        }
    }
}

The second version is always faster for all sizes of matrices (I tested dimensions 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000 and 5000). Both versions execute the similar number of instructions. I also measured total memory data volume (reads and writes) using LIKWID and the first version tranfers slightly less data from the memory to the CPU.
The speedup is generally bigger for bigger matrices. I don't understand what's going on. I would assume the hardware is doing some kind of write combining, but I would expect the total data volume to be much lower for the second version - because it modifies whole cache lines.
I am running on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10210U laptop. LIKWID is using DRAM_READS and DRAM_WRITES event counters to calculate the total memory volume.
Any information is appreciated. Also, if you can point me to some resources about the optimizations in the memory subsystems in modern processors, I would be very grateful.

Complied with what compiler with what optimization options?  Can you link a version that compiles on https://godbolt.org/, e.g. a function that takes pointer args, or use global variable if that's what your test case was.

What is the value of TILE_SIZE in practice?

https://godbolt.org/z/dPazMWeeh

Optimization options -O3 -mavx2. Used gcc for this.

@JérômeRichard It's 16

I didn't see your comment until Martin's answer bumped the question since you didn't @ notify me.  And since the title asks about the very surprising behaviour of scattered writes being less bad than scattered reads (which I didn't notice is the opposite of what you say in the question body), I wasn't going to try to explain why that might be without full details.

I think I can at least partially answer the OP's question which is asked in the wrong handedness in the title. It is actually that sequential writes are much faster because they are buffered by hardware in a cunning way that makes the system cache behave very much better than you might ordinarily expect (for moderately big matrices). Scatter gun writes are slow (about 3x slower), whilst scatter gun reads are only about 30% slower.
What happens depends critically on two interacting factors. The matrix dimensions (which I have taken to be square since that simplifies things) and the tile size. I made a quick benchmark code to compare the two algorithms in the question above (corrected I think to actually transpose the input matrix) and also with the simple untiled version in read and write sequential forms. This is the code. Additional experiments and suggested improvements are welcome also results on other architectures would be interesting.
#include <iostream>
#include <intrin.h>

#define MAXN 7200

void transpose0r(int* in, int* out, int ii_end, int jj_end, int tile_size)
{
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii++) {
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj ++) {
            out[jj * ii_end + ii ] = in[ii * jj_end + jj ];
        }
    }
}

void transpose0w(int* in, int* out, int ii_end, int jj_end, int tile_size)
{
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii++) {
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj++) {
            out[ii * jj_end + jj] = in[jj * ii_end + ii];
        }
    }
}

// NB these are unsafe if array size is not an exact multiple of tile_size!

void transpose1(int* in, int* out, int ii_end, int jj_end, int tile_size)
{
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii += tile_size) {
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj += tile_size) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < tile_size; i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < tile_size; j++) {
                    out[(jj + j) * ii_end + ii + i] = in[(ii + i) * jj_end + jj + j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void transpose2(int* in, int* out, int ii_end, int jj_end, int tile_size)
{
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < ii_end; ii += tile_size) {
        for (size_t jj = 0; jj < jj_end; jj += tile_size) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < tile_size; i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < tile_size; j++) {
                   out[(ii + i) * jj_end + jj + j] = in[(jj + j) * ii_end + ii + i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void init(int* in, int maxi, int maxj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxi; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < maxj; j++) in[i * maxj + j] = i * 10000 + j;
}

void benchmark(void (*trans)(int*, int*, int, int, int), int *a, int *b, int N, int tile_size, int repeats = 5)
{
    int i, j=0;
    int64_t t[20];

    printf("\n%4i %3i ", N, tile_size);
    init(a, N, N);
    init(b, N, N);
    for (i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
    {
        t[j++] = __rdtsc();
        (*trans)(a, b, N, N, tile_size);
        t[j++] = __rdtsc();
        (*trans)(b, a, N, N, tile_size);
        t[j++] = __rdtsc();
    }
    for (i = 0; i<j; i +=3)
        printf("%10i %10i ", (int)(t[i + 1] - t[i]), (int)(t[i + 2] - t[i + 1]));
}

void test_N(void (*trans)(int*, int*, int, int, int), int* a, int* b, int tile_size)
{  
    int i, j, N; 
    printf("\n\nN  TILE  ");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("\t t%i", i);
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXN / 4; i += i)
    {
        for (j = 5; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            N = i * j;
            if ((N % 256 == 0) && (N <= MAXN) && (N % tile_size == 0))
                benchmark(trans, a, b, N - tile_size, tile_size);
            if ((N <= MAXN) && (N % tile_size == 0)) benchmark(trans, a, b, N, tile_size);
            if ((N % 256 == 0) && (N <= MAXN) && (N % tile_size == 0))
                benchmark(trans, a, b, N + tile_size, tile_size);
        }
    }
}

void test_tile(void (*trans)(int*, int*, int, int, int), int* a, int* b)
{
//  insert interesting values in here to torment the cache algorithm more efficiently. 
//    int testTILE[] = { 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12,15,16,18,20,24, 25, 30, 32,   36, 40, 45, 48, 50, 60, 72, 75, 80, 90, 96,  100, 120, 144, 150, 180, 200, 250 };
//   for (int tidx = 0; tidx < sizeof(testTILE) / sizeof(int); tidx++)
    for (int tidx = 4; tidx <= 512; tidx++)
    {
        int tile_size;
        int N, M = MAXN / tidx;
        tile_size = tidx;
        N = M * tile_size; // round down to nearest multiple of tile_size
        benchmark(trans, a, b, N, tile_size);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int *a, *b;
    a = (int *) malloc(4 * MAXN * MAXN);
    b = (int *) malloc(4 * MAXN * MAXN);
    if ((a != NULL) && (b != NULL))
    {   
        printf("\n\nTranspose1 seqR");
        test_N(transpose1, a, b, 16); 
        printf("\n\nTranspose2 seqW");
        test_N(transpose2, a, b, 16);
/*      
        // these are *very* slow
        printf("\n\nTranspose0R seqR");
        test_N(transpose0r, a, b, 16);
        printf("\n\nTranspose0W seqW");
        test_N(transpose0w, a, b, 16);
*/
        printf("\ntest TILE_SIZE Transpose1\n");
        test_tile(transpose1, a, b);
        printf("\ntest TILE_SIZE Transpose1\n");
        test_tile(transpose2, a, b);
    }

}

I am using an Intel i5-12600 and MSC/ICX (both compilers give the same basic results but Intel has lower loop overheads making differences more stark). Compilers allowed optimising for speed release build.
The biggest problem is that when the stride is a multiple of 4096 bytes (1024 int's) the associative cache performance is severely compromised.  This means that array lengths or strides that are a multiple of 4096 bytes long are penalised heavily (up to ~6x slower worst case on scatter gun writes).
This problem is asymmetric across read and write (due to the extra sequential write buffering hardware). It is mentioned in this thread about matrix transpose & cache.
In short it means that scatter gun reads plus sequential writes using hardware assistance can be much faster than scatter gun writes with sequential read (especially for large powers of 2). However, it does depend on size and things change again when the arrays get very big.
For small arrays N<300 (except for 2^N) the simplest untiled sequential write wins. For medium sizes N<=4096 the tiled sequential write code wins out and then for larger sizes with the exception of multiples of 1024 the sequential read empirically seems to just have the edge.
I tested on a maximum array size of 7200 chosen as 2*60^2 so as to have lots of small prime factors and allow testing up to 7x1024. To highlight the bizarre timings for array lengths that are of the form 2^N I have made the testing code so that all tests on multiples of 256 will be bracketed either side by N+/-TILE_SIZE to emphasise the spike (and prevent a join the dots problem when the arrays get very big).
These are the resulting performance graphs TILE_SIZE=16 to match OPs tests for small matrix (N<1024) showing timing detail, medium matrix (N<4096) showing the exhaustion of system level cache and larger arrays respectively:



Here T0_R, T0_W are sequential R & W respectively and T1_R is sequential read, T2_W is sequential write. Note that the advantage that T2_W holds vanishes for N>409 (apart from for multiples of 1024). The humps in the T0 graphs for small arrays are real the data are well sampled. T0R/W not shown on the large arrays graph since they get huge very quickly.
To run the benchmarks I had the machine idle and left it to run flat out. Analysis I took the fastest time out of the 10 repeats per line as indicative of what the time was. Smallest array timings are still a bit noisy.
I decided to investigate this further since although I have never found my code to be much of a performance bottleneck I was curious to see what was happening here and also to survey good/bad values for TILE_SIZE.
My machine has 6x48k L1 cache, 6x1.25M + 2M L2 cache and 20MB L3 cache.
With two arrays in play simultaneously and using 2M (500k ints) & 20M (5M ints) as guide sizes we might expect to exhaust L2 cache at N=500 and L3 cache at N=1600 this is borne out by the graphs above.
Now turning to Jerome's question about tile size I decided to do an empirical test. I usually go for 32 myself. I made a routine that tries every possible TILE_SIZE from 4 to 512 inclusive on the largest possible array and if necessary reduces the array size from 7200 to the next lower exact multiple of TILE_SIZE. The results are interesting and not what I would have predicted.
To compare the results I compute Time(N)/N^2 so that it gives a time per element moved. Here is the graph with spikes in the expected places but also some in unexpected (at least to me) places as well. I am sure a better mathematician than I can look at this pattern are work out the associative cache algorithm. Mostly the results are very good but the outliers are bad.

The rough rule of thumb is that for most cases the sequential write tiled transpose wins out unless the matrix is small (N<300) or large (N>4096). Then the best performance depends mostly on whether or not N is a multiple of 1024. I find the tolerance of a wide variety of TILE_SIZE somewhat surprising and it might possibly be an artefact of my original choice of NMAX.
I can't explain why the tables are turned for the largest matrices...

You wrote "sequential writes are much faster because they are buffered by hardware in a cunning way that makes the system cache behave very much better than you might ordinarily expect (for moderately big matrices)." Do you have any more detail why this is the case?

There was a thread about the Write Combining Buffers implementation on Stack Overflow about 3 years back with some more detail. Intel apparently calls them the superqueue and AMD uses WCB. It is more that for some awkward strides that scatter gun writes become exceedingly slow when N gets big (whereas scattergun reads seem to degrade more gracefully). More experiments would be needed to refine this empirical observation.

@Bogi: Scattered writes also take more cache traffic: a write can't commit from the store buffer until the cache line is read into the core (with exclusive ownership).  If it's evicted from L1d (and even L2) before another write to it happens, it's dirty so has to get written back to L2 or even L3, instead of just dropped.  Or even to DRAM if evicted from L3. Having to wait for write-back slows whatever wanted to allocate a new line. Mixed read+write workloads are a bit slower for DRAM controllers, and with every write effectively costing a cache-line read+write, total traffic is higher.

@Bogi: re: the store buffer itself, see Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM? .  And semi-related: How does memory reordering help processors and compilers? re: the difference between stores and loads as far as CPUs are concerned.  Normally loads are more important than stores to get done quickly to be able to find more instruction-level parallelism, but in this case it's a throughput limitation.

@PeterCordes any thoughts about why WCB loses effectiveness at around N=4096? I have plenty of ram so that isn't the cause. I don't like numerology but it does look a bit suspicious. The slow tile size spikes in the later test are mostly at obvious powers of two and 7/8, 3/4 thereof. Erratics include 67, 107, 176 and a few other low multiples of primes like 11, 17, 31, 71, 73.  I was a bit surprised by the nearly flat baseline once away from the loop overheads of tiny tile sizes. I've always used 32 in the past. It looks to me like 53, 54 or 55 would be faster by ~20% according to my plot.

@MartinBrown: My first guess would be aliasing in L1d leading to many more conflict misses since 4K offsets index the same set in L1d cache.  And/or maybe 4k-aliasing between stores and loads reducing memory-level parallelism.  L1 memory bandwidth: 50% drop in efficiency using addresses which differ by 4096+64 bytes / Understanding 4K aliasing on Intel CPU's / Why does the speed of memcpy() drop dramatically every 4KB?
